# Ajax for login check not working and submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know there are many answers about my problem but I'm new to ajax and javascript I would like someone to point me to the problem causing my script to fail.
I made login check with ajax based on this answer [Check if user logged in on ajax page change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045416/check-if-user-logged-in-on-ajax-page-change) . When the submit button is clicked the function checks if the user is logged in or not. I want to display an alert if its not and to proceed to next page if it is.
My javascript:

```
    $('#bookForm').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url : '<?=BASE_URL?>user/logged.php',
            success : function(response){
                if (response.logged == true) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    alert('you need to log in');
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
    });
});
```

My php script that checks if the user is logged:

```
$response = array();

if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {

    $response['logged'] = false; 

}else{

    $response['logged'] = true;

}

$response = json_encode($response);

echo($response);
```

I'm new to javascript/ajax and I'm not sure where the problem is. The function returns the alert for not logged in user despite the user being logged in.

Comment: Remove the `return json_encode($response); `

Comment: And echo does not need braces so `echo $response;`

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server? How are you setting `BASE_URL`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard BASE_URL is constant - working, errors - none, library - yes, web-server - yes

Comment: What does your JSON string look like? Can you `console.log(response)`? Show us the markup for the form.

Comment: `Object {logged: true}` when logged and `Object {logged: false}` when not. It's working as far as I see.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Each element should have quotes `{"logged": "true"}`. You will need to change the variable values to strings by quoting them `$response['logged'] = "false";`

Comment: I've managed to add quotes to the true/false but couldn't to "logged"

Comment: `logged` should have quotes automatically based on the test I just ran. `{"logged":"false"}`

Comment: If I open directly logged.php I see this `{"logged":"true"}` but in the console -  `Object {logged: "true"}` . Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Do you have `dataType: 'json',` before the success function? How many forms do you have on the HTML page?

Comment: Yes I have added it. Could it be the ajax function itself? I have only one form.

Comment: Make sure you change to using a string here: `if (response.logged == 'true') {`.... You're testing a Boolean, but a string is returned.

Comment: I have changed it before but I was trying `this.logged` and it wasn't working. I changed it to `response.logged` and worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this option : `dataType:'json'` in your ajax call.

And echo json_encode($response); without any return.

Comment: I've added the dataType and removed the return but same result - always false

Comment: Did you change the displayed value in php by the json encoded version ?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your Jquery code.

```
$('#bookForm').submit(function(event){

event.preventdefault();

    $.ajax({

        url : '<?= BASE_URL ?>user/logged.php',
        dataType:'json'
        success : function(response){

            if (response.logged == true) {
                return true;
            } 
            else{
                alert('you need to log in');
                //e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Remove the `return json_encode($response);` from php script

Comment: It is a good idea to add that, but it does not answer that actual question

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: the form is not submitting but the if statement is always false regardless of user being logged in

Comment: @A.L. Have you added `session_start();` at the start of your php script?

Comment: Yes I have in included file.

Comment: In your php script, add `var_dump($_SESSION);` before `if` condition and check whether it is printing your `userId` or not.